# Please help me find this fantasy live action series that was probably released in 2010

Tags: story-identification, tv

The show has five teenagers each of whom has a stone related to an element: fire, thunder, electricity, rain. The name of characters as far as I remember are Fire, Electra, Rain, and Sky.

It starts with Rain and Sky who meet a professor who guides them about these things. Another major story arc is that they have to find the stones and give them to their rightful owners.

They also need to stop the evil guy from finding it because the evil guy is trying to steal these stones. They fight evil minions of the bad guy in another dimension with cards and stuff but they definitely go to a different dimension for this. Their power level increases once they defeat a particular villain and the main character can lose their stone if they start to lose in a battle.

I watched it in 2010 but I don't remember if that is the original air date.

Comment: You say five teenagers, but only ever list four. Also have a look at the guidance [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: Sorry I dont remember all the names ,like I said a lot of details evade me I watched it when I was a kid.

Comment: Did the teenagers have special costumes, or did they wear regular clothes?

Comment: What country did you see this in? What language?

Comment: @LogicDictates When they went to the other dimension they switched to a different costume ,which had helmets specific to their stone colours

Comment: @ArlettaS I watched it in Hindi , but the majority of the cast was asian and I am pretty sure it was dubbed.

Comment: Brings to mind [*Armor Hero*](https://armorhero.fandom.com/wiki/Armor_Hero), but I don't see any mention of a professor that brings them together.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No this is not it ,this is more power ranger style .

Comment: @TimeTraveller: Ah, so more suits than armor?

Comment: @TimeTraveller South Asian or East Asian (or elsewhere)?

Comment: @OrangeDog I wouldn't really remeber I am sorry I was just a kid ,I don't rember a whole lot of details .

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes more suits and really nothing like power rangers there was no morphing situation going on ,they just switched to suits (If i remember correctly) when they went to alternate dimension for fighting

Comment: Did the helmets cover their faces, like Power Ranger style helmets, or were their faces still visible with the helmets on?

Comment: @TimeTraveller you keep saying you remember they were Asian, but you don't know what you mean by Asian?

Comment: @LogicDictates There faces were visible partially ,not entirely

Comment: @OrangeDog ,by that I mean I don't remember  if it was east asia(china ,korea etc) or west asia because the information eludes me ,I remember it being asian because I probably made a mental note of it .Instead of giving incorrect information I gave the general of what I remebered to be exactly correct.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thanks for your answer browsing through more info on armor hero turns out armor hero was inspired by king of warriors and that's how i found it,thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The show I was looking for is ***[King of Warrior EX](https://tokusatsu.fandom.com/wiki/King_of_Warrior_EX)*** (2007).

> The main character's parents are researchers at a university. One day, they opened a gate to a different dimension. Xu Feng, the male protagonist, and his friend Qiu Yu starts to uncover the secrets of Xu's parent's research, leading them to discovery of other lifeforms from the other dimension. Xu Feng gains other members to his team whom all have talismans of different attributes. They must battle against the villain Elder Dragon and his 7 seven dark warriors with spinning tops.

The dubbed version changed the names. Thanks to everyone who  tried.

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours have elapsed since the question was first posted.

Answer (score 0):

Could be Sport Ranger

https://tokusatsu.fandom.com/wiki/Sport_Ranger#Plot

> ........Upon further research, Dr. Earth created "SportDetector" to control the 5 broken pieces and special suits to utilize each piece's unique power. He gave five youngsters the suits to stop these monsters.

Comment: What are the character's names?

Comment: Other than a standard 5 man band, does anything about this match?

Comment: No not really ,This is not the same again I am pretty sure it was not power ranger style.+they wore the stones as necklaces

Comment: @DavidW Asian characters, Professor guide and stones to be given